# iam trying to get datable specific columns which has null value using linq in vb.net get only those 2 empty rows

Tags: vb.net

When I check the column values in a `DataTable` using LINQ, they are not equal.  Here is the code I'm using which has the problem:

for eg if columnA 5 rows which two or empty ir null i should

```
DT.
    Select("Source <> ('AMEX','VISA')").
    ToList().
    ForEach(Sub(row) row(ColumnExpType)="T")
```

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more clear and to format it properly, but I could only take it so far because I wasn't sure what you meant.  Please edit your question to correct it if I got anything wrong.  So, my main question is, when you say that the values are not equal, what do you mean by that?  They are not equal with what?

Comment: Hmmm.  Upon re-reading your original title, I think I may have misunderstood.  Maybe all you meant by "Not Equal" is that you were doing a `<>` comparison in the `Select` method.  But, if so, I still don't understand your problem.  If that's the case, what columns are you getting and how is that different than what you were expecting it to return?

Comment: Sir iam trying to get datable specific columns which has null value using linq in vb.net for eg iff cola 5 rows which two or empty ir null i should get only those 2 empty rows

Comment: So you want to get all the rows in the `DataTable` which are null or empty in a particular column?

Comment: Yes sir need empty rows kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the rows, using LINQ, which have NULL in ColumnA you could do something like this:

```
DT.Rows().
    Cast(Of DataRow).Where(Function(row) row("ColumnA") Is DBNull.Value)
```

However, depending on your needs, you may prefer to use the old `Select` method:

```
DT.Select("ColumnA IS NOT NULL")
```

If you also need to check if the column contains an empty string, then to do that with `Select`:

```
DT.Select("ColumnA IS NOT NULL OR ColumnA = ''")
```

But, if you want to use LINQ, then it depends on the type of the column and whether it's a typed `DataTable` (a table from a typed `DataSet`).  If the column is a standard string type, like `NVARCHAR` in T-SQL, and the `DataTable` is just a standard non-typed `DataTable`, then you could do something like this:

```
DT.Rows().
    Cast(Of DataRow).
    Where(Function(row) row("ColumnA") Is DBNull.Value Or DirectCast(row("ColumnA"), String) = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select("Source <> ('AMEX','VISA')")` will not work.

You need

```
Select("Source <> 'AMEX' And Source <> 'VISA'")
```

Not sure what the For Each is doing. This is a working example of using my test database.

```
    Dim lst = dt.Select("Rating <> 'Unrated' And Rating <>'Good'").ToList
    For Each dr As DataRow In lst
        Debug.Print(dr("Name").ToString)
    Next
```